# Can't sort queue items in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm utterly baffled by this and I think I must be doing something wrong. Is it possible that MS actually neglected to add sorting ability to queue items? Here's my queue item view of Service Activities:

[image: no sorting???]

I must be missing something? How can people use queue items without sorting?

Comment: I found this site which suggests sorting by related entities is a limitation of FetchXML in CRM. The only solution seems to be some kind of rollup field.  http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/59661a4e-0f40-4198-9d96-94e2941ba503

Comment: I didn't see this comment before answering, but you're spot on: you can't sort by related entities due to the way FetchXML works. In *most* cases, sorting by "Entered Queue" has been perfect for customers I've worked with - if you need some more complex sorting please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **Entered Queue** column to your view (it's part of the *Queue Item* entity).

System views can only sort on columns on the view being shown, not on related columns. In your example above every column is part of the "Regarding" relationship, which may be a related Contact/Case/Activity/Opportunity/whatever. There's no guarantee that the regarding record even exists for each queue item, so it's not possible to sort by it.

"Entered Queue" is in the default view - just add it back and sort by that, and you'll get items added to the queue the longest time period ago float to the top of the list as you'd expect.

Comment: Is there a solution or approach you can recommend for using custom development or mappings to accomplish the goal?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry - it is a limitation of the views/FetchXML. In most cases you should be right to just add back "Entered Queue" and sort by that - items show up in the order they were added to the queue.